# On mouseenter div animate ease

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have question about hovering.

```
$(".hover li img").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".overlay").animate({
        left: pixels+"px"
    });
});
```

**Class overlay is** transparent box around image, with red border.

I want when hover on some img, border go there. And it isn't problem for me.
My problem is when hover on first,second, third, forth,fifth, and stop on sixth image. But fast moving over image. My overlay class stops for a moment on every image.

**My question is** : How to overlay class not stop on every image after moving mouse over it. I appreciate answer, thanks anyway

Comment: have you tried reducing the duration of seconds as a second parameter to the animate function?

Comment: @AbdulBasit yes,and failed :/

Comment: try adding  $(".overlay").stop(true,true); before animate?

Comment: @AbdulBasit how to do it? put answer about this

Comment: i have edited the answer, if it can help to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you to calculate the left according to the current image's offet left
like for example only

```
$(".hover li img").mouseenter(function() {
that  = this;
  $(".overlay").stop(true,false);
$(".overlay").animate({
    left: that.offset().left+"px"
});
 });
```

or

```
  $(".hover li img").mouseenter(function() {

  $(".overlay").stop(true,false);
 $(".overlay").animate({
    left: pixels+"px"
});
 });
```

Comment: now when moving mouse, I can't explane how, but when moving over images, it not easing, go on mobile.de and one of ads, ang look images, move your mouse over it, to see what I want

Comment: cant find that example, you will have to add html as well and pixel logic to elaborate

Comment: I find the problem .stop(true,false) is solution,just edit your answer